# Getting rid of vertical spaces between images in table

Tags: css, image, margin, padding

I have page with a split image (filter from `Gimp`) but I see horizontal lines between the images. How can I remove these vertical spaces? Please see http://quaaoutlodge.com/content/christmas-green-fee-special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `line-height: 0;` for all `td` it will fix the issue

the images act as a `inline-block` element which creates a `white-space` to fix `vertical` white space between `inline-block` you need to set `line-height` to `0`